# Exec Function on terminal

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've created a shell script and I want to `Exec` a function on a terminal.

For example:

```
function update () {
     sudo apt update
}

function Exec () {
    xfce4-terminal --maximize -x "$1"
}
```

But when I execute this:

`Exec "update"` or `Exec "$(update)"`

I get this error: `Failed to execute child process "update" (No such file or directory)`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: This is the Error message :
Failed to execute child process "update" (No such file or directory)

Comment: Are you trying to pass the update function to the Exec function and have it run as the $1 parameter?

Comment: yes right 
but all what i want is the update function run on stand terminal

Comment: `xfce4-terminal` expects the name of an executable file, not a shell function.

Comment: i know but i want it work with function not only executable file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

The `update` function exists only in your shell process. The `xfce4-terminal` process has no visibility to it. The argument to `-x` has to be an executable command, not a shell function.

What you can do is create a shell script that does the same thing as your `update` function (make sure it's executable and installed somewhere in your `$PATH`) and pass the name of that shell script to `xfce4-terminal`.

Or, in this particular case, you could just do:

```
xfce4-terminal --maximize -x sudo apt update
```

or you could pass `sudo apt update` as the argument to your `Exec` function. But in general the only way (well, almost) to make a series of shell commands visible to external programs is to wrap them in a shell script.

Comment: i know and thnx but i cant run a function inside terminal ?

Comment: You can only run a shell function inside the shell that defined it.